# Sympy integrate error: can't convert symbols to int

Tags: python, sympy

Trying to integrate a `Piecewise` function in Sympy throws the error `TypeError: can't convert symbols to int`. I did not find useful info about this error online.

The integral should not involve any integers. I am not sure why anything would need to be converted to `int`. The function in the example below is simplified - I actually need to integrate more complicated piecewise functions depending on parameters.

Code:

```
import sympy as sy

h1, h2 = sy.symbols("h_1 h_2", positive=True)
vy = sy.symbols("v_Y", real=True)

h1 = 1.5
h2 = 0.5

pdfy = sy.Piecewise((h1, (0<=vy)&(vy<=(1-h2)/h1)), (h2, ((1-h2)/h1<vy)&(vy<=1)), (0,True))
print(pdfy.evalf(0.1))
print(sy.integrate(vy*(pdfy.evalf(vy)),(vy,0.9,1)))
```

Output:

```
Piecewise((0.e+0, (v_Y >= 0) & (v_Y <= 0.333333333333333)), (0.e+0, (v_Y <= 1) & (v_Y >     0.333333333333333)), (0, True))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-69fbacdbf6ac> in <module>
     10 pdfy = sy.Piecewise((h1, (0<=vy)&(vy<=(1-h2)/h1)), (h2, ((1-h2)/h1<vy)&(vy<=1)),         (0,True))
     11 print(pdfy.evalf(0.1))
---> 12 print(sy.integrate(vy*(pdfy.evalf(vy)),(vy,0.9,1)))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/core/evalf.py in evalf(self, n, subs, maxn, chop,     strict, quad, verbose)
   1435         if not evalf_table:
   1436             _create_evalf_table()
-> 1437         prec = dps_to_prec(n)
   1438         options = {'maxprec': max(prec, int(maxn*LG10)), 'chop': chop,
   1439                'strict': strict, 'verbose': verbose}

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpmath/libmp/libmpf.py in dps_to_prec(n)
     65     """Return the number of bits required to represent n decimals
     66     accurately."""
---> 67     return max(1, int(round((int(n)+1)*3.3219280948873626)))
     68 
     69 def repr_dps(n):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/core/expr.py in __int__(self)
    291         from sympy import Dummy
    292         if not self.is_number:
--> 293             raise TypeError("can't convert symbols to int")
    294         r = self.round(2)
    295         if not r.is_Number:

TypeError: can't convert symbols to int
```

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error, when you call `pdfy.evalf(vy)` , evalf call dps_to_prec(vy), which requires a number as the parameter. However vy is a symbol you got from `sy.symbols("v_Y", real=True)`. Therefore, python is giving the error `TypeError: can't convert symbols to int`

Comment: Thank you - I only added the `evalf()` to get around a previous error. Cannot reproduce this error now, so your solution works.